# '<' not supported between instances of str and int

Tags: python, string, integer, min, nested-lists

I'm trying to figure out the lowest score amongst a group of people.

My code:

```
list = [['Radhe',99],['Bajrangi',98],['Ram',95],['Shyam',94],['Bharat',89]]
min_score = list[0][1]
for x in list:
    for y in x:
        if (y < min_score):
            min_score=y
print(min_score)
```

What should I do different?

Comment: Your `x` item is a list of two entites, a `string` and the `int`. The `for y in x` yields the str, then the int for each _if_ statement. Hence your very first test is checking `"Radhe"` against `99`.

Comment: `min(your_lst, key=lambda x: x[1])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `list` is a built-in-data type in python so you should rename the variable to something else such as `l`
2. in your first for loop you are doing `for x in list` so you are assigning x to the first element of list which is `['Radhe', 99]`. In your second for loop you are going through each item in x, the first of which is `'Radhe'` and hence you are comparing an int to a string.

Considering this, you can rewrite your code as:

```
l = [['Radhe',99],['Bajrangi',98],['Ram',95],['Shyam',94],['Bharat',89]]
min_score = l[0][1]
for x in l:
    if (x[1] < min_score):
        min_score=x[1]
print(min_score)
```

which outputs:

```
89
```

alternatively you can use list comprehension to do it all in one line:

```
min_score = min([x[1] for x in l])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over *every* element of `x`, when you really only care about `x[1]`:

```
for x in list:
    if x[1] < min_score:
        min_score = x[1]
```

You can also unpack each sublist to give the values easier names to work with:

```
for name, score in list:
    if score < min_score:
        min_score = score
```

Comment: yup i see it now, Thanks!!

Comment: There's a new glitch. I'm not able to compare float and str despite deploying the piece of amends. Here's the code:                                                                                                n = int(input())
list = []
for i in range(n+1):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    list.append([name,score])
print(list)

min_scores = list[0][1]
for x in list:
    if (x[1]<min):
        min_scores = x[1]
    list.remove(min)
print(list)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
given_list = [['Radhe',99],['Bajrangi',98],['Ram',95],['Shyam',94],['Bharat',89]]
print(min(given_list, key=lambda x: x[1])[1])
```

Comment: There's a new glitch. I'm not able to compare float and str despite deploying the piece of amends. Here's the code: n = int(input()) list = [] for i in range(n+1): name = input() score = float(input()) list.append([name,score]) print(list) min_scores = list[0][1] for x in list: if (x[1]<min): min_scores = x[1] list.remove(min) print(list)

Comment: @dubey ..Please add this to original question and ask a separate question in stack overflow...It is little hard to read the code snippets in comment section